# How to check and compare three column values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns based on which I want to generate result. Lets say if any user has secured `70` and above in anyone the subject then that should be counted as passed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=IFERROR(IF(LARGE(B2:D2,1)>=70,"Pass","Fail"),"Not Attempted")
```

I assume "N/A" is a text.